# searching an easy component to upload images with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js, ng-file-upload

I searching something like dropzone but work more easily. what I want is just a component which I use and then call my upload function (angularjs function) don't need to specify the url (for the dropzone component).
I found this component: [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) but in terms of design I need more!! something like the dropzone which means:

when I Upload the image it's displayed in the component in success case any suggestion please

Comment: the module you referenced has that feature...dig deeper into examples and docs

Comment: thank you for your replay but which component do you mean?

Comment: the one and only one you mentioned and linked to

Comment: have a look at the demo page mentioned in the docs that might be what you want.

Comment: you mean this: https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/ but what I want is when I upload the image it's displayed instead of the text (Select File or Drop File)